# How to call SOAP web services from JAVA

Tags: java, web-services

I want to know that how we can call SOAP web services from GET and POST request from java program.

Comment: google your own title and find things like jax-ws (e.g, http://cxf.apache.org/) (

Comment: You would start by doing some prior research. And sorry, asking such broad questions here ... doesn't count as such.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am sorry, but your question doesnt fit into the Stack Overflow format. Be sure to check out [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class HttpURLConnectionExample{

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

        //System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        //http.sendGet();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://http://localhost/getmiweb/public/api/v1/OrderAPI";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://http://localhost/getmiweb/public/api/v1/OrderAPI";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        //Passing Parameters
        String urlParameters = "token=t0ocgQ/jj8YbjasuLYJ12KJoZmaLNt4zUcEZZKxCU6E=&orderId=12345";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's SOAP?